# javascript in onkeypress value

Tags: javascript, html

For the below text box:

```
<input type="text" style="" onkeypress="javascript:doit_onkeypress(event);" />
```

this script is working fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function doit_onkeypress(event){
    if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.which == 13){
      // here my action works
    }
  }
</script>
```

But my problem is images (instead of text area) are creating dynamically.

i am trying to execute same  as

```
<input type="text" style="" onkeypress="  <script type="text/javascript">
  function doit_onkeypress(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.which == 13) {
      // here my action works
    }
  }
 </script>" />
```

is it possible as above with modifications?

why because for dynamically generating images i can't write java script on key press actions for every image. every image the action url is different.

Comment: <input type="text" style="" onkeypress="<script type="text/javascript">
            function doit_onkeypress(event){
                if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.which == 13){
                    here my action works
                }
            }
        </script> " /> is it possible?

Comment: Try to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

Comment: Why you do not use first code, where is the problem in first ?

Comment: My images are generating dynamically. for every image onkeypress we have to hit diff urls.

Comment: Can you show your code where you create those images?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass target with the `doit_onkeypress()` method and make only one keypress method. From target, you can get your actionURL.

Answer (score 0):

There can be only `js` code inside `onkeypress=` value.

You cannot paste `html` code such as `<script>` there.

There is not enought info about dynamic images  part to help further.